# Where to find the book 'Hoshen ha-Mishpat shel ha-Kohen ha-Gadol' by Rabbi Yudel Rosenberg?

Tags: jewish-books, maharal

Does anyone know where (online preferably) I can access Rabbi Rosenberg's book 'Hoshen ha-Mishpat shel ha-Kohen ha-Gadol'? (The one about the Maharal and the Choshen Ha-Mishpat)

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's available in Hebrew on Hebrewbooks. Here's a link:

https://hebrewbooks.org/21491

And some interesting background info on the story and on Rabbi Rosenberg by Rabbi Prof. Shnayer Leiman:

https://leimanlibrary.com/texts_of_publications/83.%20The%20Adventure%20of%20the%20Maharal%20of%20Prague%20in%20London.pdf

https://www.yutorah.org/lectures/lecture.cfm/736269/dr-shnayer-leiman/golem-of-prague-fact-or-fiction/